# throwing file exceed Exception to client in java servlet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I have an html `type="file"` which users get to choose a file and send it to server using ajax.

Here is my script:

```
@MultipartConfig(
    location="D:\\", 
    fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024,    // 1 MB
    maxFileSize=1024*1024*5,        // 5 MB 
    maxRequestSize=1024*1024*5*5    // 25 MB
)

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try{
        MultipartRequest multipartRequest = new MultipartRequest(request, "D:\\");
    } catch(IOException e){
        out.println("File size is too high");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    out.print("File uploaded Successfully Uploaded");
}
```

Client-size Ajax:

```
 if(formdata){
        $.ajax({
            url: '../servlet',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            async : false,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Now here is the problem part, I need to restrict files with higher size than 1MB. As long as the file size sent from client is lower that 1MB it works fine and My `alert box` Pops me `File uploaded Successfully Uploaded` message just as expected in my client-side but if the file size is higher than 1MB In my server console I can see the `e.getMessage` printout exception saying about file size exceeded message but I don't see it in my client side although I have set server to send `File size is too high` to client but I never get to see the message in client.

Comment: have you  render data from "servlet" method to client side?? as your giving ajax call ??

Comment: which file upload plugin your using???

Comment: I am using `oreilly` and @DipakThoke I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: please check callback function for that plugin  can you give the docs link to me?

Comment: are you using jquery plugin to upload file to server this what i'm aksing?

Comment: no I am not using Jquery plugin,